# Visual Studio publish to custom Docker container fails due to non-existent Dockerfile directory

Tags: visual-studio, docker, visual-studio-2015

I'm following Scott Hanselman's article [Brainstorming development workflows with Docker, Kitematic, VirtualBox, Azure, ASP.NET, and Visual Studio](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BrainstormingDevelopmentWorkflowsWithDockerKitematicVirtualBoxAzureASPNETAndVisualStudio.aspx) and failing during the publish process.

To set the stage, I've got [Docker Toolbox](https://www.docker.com/docker-toolbox) (as of 2/11/16), Visual Studio 2015, [Visual Studio 2015 Tools for Docker](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0f5b2caa-ea00-41c8-b8a2-058c7da0b3e4) (as of 2/11/16) and [ASP.NET RC 1](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=627627).

My publish dialog looks as follows (I present this not to show specific settings but rather to show where I am in the process):

[image: Visual Studio Publish dialog]

> Error: An error occured during publish.
>
> The command [docker --tlsverify
>   --tlscacert="C:\Users\bla\.docker\machine\certs\ca.pem" --tlscert="C:\Users\bla\.docker\machine\certs\cert.pem" --tlskey="C:\Users\bla\.docker\machine\certs\key.pem" -H tcp://192.168.99.100:2376 build -t devwkflowtest -f
>   "C:\Users\bla\AppData\Local\Temp\PublishTemp\zapp29\approot\src\zapp\Properties\PublishProfiles\v"
>   "C:\Users\bla\AppData\Local\Temp\PublishTemp\zapp29"] exited with code
>   [1](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BrainstormingDevelopmentWorkflowsWithDockerKitematicVirtualBoxAzureASPNETAndVisualStudio.aspx): unable to process Dockerfile: read
>   C:\Users\bla\AppData\Local\Temp\PublishTemp\zapp29\approot\src\zapp\Properties\PublishProfiles\v:
>   The handle is invalid.

The Dockerfile can't be found (and hence the invalid handle error) because the `\v` directory shown in the path does not exist.

Manually creating it was not helpful because that part of the publish path is deleted and recreated during the publish operation.

Answer (score 0):

Poking around I found that my publish profile:

[image: Publish Profile section of Solution Explorer]

had the value `v` for `<DockerfileRelativePath>`:

[image: DockerfileRelativePath value]

Some Googling lead me to https://github.com/Lybecker/ContainerWorkshop/tree/master/Exercise06 which had `<DockerfileRelativePath>..\..\Dockerfile</DockerfileRelativePath>`.

I changed `v` to `..\..\Dockerfile` and the publish completed successfully.

I don't understand how the `v` was generated and I also don't understand why it shouldn't have worked regardless; I'd expect `v` to refer to `\.v` and work.